# Issue with API GET response format

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, get, map-function

I am making a get request to an api and then trying to map over the request. My issue is that the response is changing from data in this usual `[{...},{...}]` to `'[[Object Object][Object Object]]'` so that when I try to map over the array, it is throwing an error. I have tried using `JSON.stringify()` but it does not work. Here is my code:

```
---- Home.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Home = () => {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const url =
      "https://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/2021/standings?standingType=HOME";

    const fetchItems = async () => {
      const apiResult = await fetch(url, {
        headers: {
          "X-Auth-Token": process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
        },
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));

      setTableData(apiResult.standings[0].table);
    };

    fetchItems();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="home-container">
      <Hero />
      <Table data={tableData} />
      <Predictions />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

------ Table.js

import TableList from "./TableList";

const Table = ({ data }) => {

  return (
    <section className="table" id="table">
      <h1 className="table-header">Table</h1>
      <div className="table-container">
         <TableList data={data} />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

--------- TableList.js

import TableCard from "./TableCard";

const TableList = ({ data }) => {

  return (
    <div className="table-list">
      {data.map((index, teamData) => {
        return <TableCard key={index} data={teamData} />;
      })} 
    </div>
  );
};
```

If I console log the mapped data, I get `'0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20'`,
instead of the data that I initially receive in the fetch request that is `[{position:1, team: {...}, gamesPlayed:9}, {...}]`.

I have never had this issue before when using a GET request to an API so any and all help is appreciated. Sorry in advance for the poor formatting.

Comment: What happends when you `console.log()` beforehand? 
Is the broblem only with the `.map`?

Comment: @Brgbegnefneg If I console.log anywhere except in the actual fetch request, I get the data as [Object Object], [Object Object]

Comment: Are you fixed issues are not? I tthink your issue in SetState